# Upgrade PostgreSQL 9.4 to 9.5 : LC_ALL unset

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my PostgreSQL 9.4 database to PostgreSQL 9.5 but everytime while running `sudo pg_upgradecluster 9.4 main` I get this error:

```
Stopping old cluster...
Disabling connections to the old cluster during upgrade...
Restarting old cluster with restricted connections...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Error: The locale requested by the environment is invalid.
Error: Could not create target cluster
```

But when I run `locale` I see the `LC_ALL` is actually set:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I can remember having the same issue while upgrading from PostgreSQL 9.3 to PostgreSQL 9.4 but that time I fixed this by adding this line to `/etc/environment`:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

But this doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After many attempts to fix this problem, this command finally worked for me:

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` shadows the `LC_CTYPE` pre-existing in the environment, which appears to be set to `UTF-8` according to Perl's error output. Unlike most programs that will just ignore it, postgres' `initdb` will fail outright on a non-existing locale. The root cause is a rogue `LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"` somewhere in your init/environment scripts.

Comment: did not work for me. Additionally I am getting this error also => Error: Could not create target cluster